# How to use "any more" with "not"?

Tags: negation, quantifiers

Is it correct to write the question: "*Are there any more problems?*"? considering that "problem" has a negative connotation to it?
and to say: "*There isn't any more problem*" or "*there aren't any more problems*"? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You only use "singular" in constructions of the form *There **isn't** any more X* if ***X*** is a [mass noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mass_noun) (such as *food, water, time* - things which unlike *problems*, can't be counted).

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence is in a negative construction, **any** is the proper word.
Check these examples:

> Are there any more problems with the house?

-

> No, there aren't any more problems.

Also, **There are** = plural, so the complement of the statement must also come in the plural form. - *Are there any more problem'**s**' with the house?* - *No, there are not any more problem'**s**' with the house.*

**There is** = singular, so it means the complement of the statement must also come in the singular form. - *Is there another problem with the house?* - *No, there is not another problem with the house.*

You can also enjoy the no longer construction, it seems much easier for me, sometimes I use it when talking about negative statements:

> There is **no longer** a problem with your house
>
> There are **no longer** problems with your house

It's also used in other negative statements, such as: *I no longer like her*. *She no longer likes me*, *I'm no longer your boyfriend*, *This house is no longer mine.*

How to build a **no longer** construction: `Subject + No longer + Verb` Or `Subject + Verb + No longer.`

Do not increase any other negative construction when using no longer, such as: He isn't no longer my boyfriend. **No longer** already functions as this role.

[No Longer - Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/no-longer-not-any-longer)

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the tire to the car, the mechanic asked

> Are there any more problems *(with the car)*?

to which the driver answered

> There aren't any more problems, it was just the flat tire.